# Read a Cookie in a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, cookies

I am trying to read a cookie sent through the client side in c# using a web service. I have got this code so far but my web service does not like request. Is there a better way to read a cookie through a web service. Just want to do it the best practice way.

```
int loop1, loop2;
HttpCookieCollection MyCookieColl;
HttpCookie MyCookie;

MyCookieColl = Request.Cookies;

// Capture all cookie names into a string array.
String[] arr1 = MyCookieColl.AllKeys;

// Grab individual cookie objects by cookie name. 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
   MyCookie = MyCookieColl[arr1[loop1]];
   Response.Write("Cookie: " + MyCookie.Name + "<br>");
   Response.Write ("Secure:" + MyCookie.Secure + "<br>");

   //Grab all values for single cookie into an object array.
   String[] arr2 = MyCookie.Values.AllKeys;

   //Loop through cookie Value collection and print all values. 
   for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) 
   {
      Response.Write("Value" + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
public String get_Cookie(String cookieName)
{
    HTTPRequest Request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName) != null)
    {
        return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName).Value);
    }
    else
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question, but I do this way:

```
    public String get_Cookie(String cookieName)
            {
                HTTPRequest Request = this.Context.Request;//Added to better understanding.

                if (Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName) != null)
                {
                    return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName).Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }
            }
```

Comment: it doesn't like request as it does not exist in my content

Comment: So how you access other details of your request? (besides cookies)